# Is it possible to limit the options in the multiple choice drop down list in REDCap?

Tags: variables, survey, redcap, fieldtype

The participants in my study are being asked "Which of the following are reasons you are planning to use x? (Please select all that apply)" via Field Type: Checkboxes (Multiple Answers). Later, they're being asked to select the 3 most important of those reasons as to why they are planning to use x.

Currently I have it structured as "Most Important" via Field Type: Multiple Choice - Drop-down List (Single Answer), with the choices being all reasons listed in the prior question "Which of the following are reasons you are planning to use x? (Please select all that apply)". Which is then followed by "2nd Most Important" and "3rd Most Important" via the same method as for "Most Important".

The issue or question that I have is, **is it possible to make the Field Type: Multiple Choice - Drop-down List (Single Answer) only display the choices that the participant had selected previously**? For example, there could be 10 options to choose from for "Which of the following are reasons you are planning to use x? (Please select all that apply)". But since the participant only selected 4 of those 10 options, only those 4 options are available to choose via Field Type: Multiple Choice - Drop-down List (Single Answer) for "Most Important", "2nd Most Important", and "3rd Most Important".

I have tried to use branching logic and other field types, but they haven't fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your second field, where respondents are asked to rank the choices they made, should be a matrix of radio fields with the 'ranking' option checked, and choices "Most important", "Second most important", "Third most important". You would repeat all of the 10 choices from the first field as question labels, and each has branching logic that displays it if the corresponding choice was checked in the first checkbox field.

To illustrate, here's my version of your first checkbox field:

[image]

And here's the matrix:

[image]

And finally, branching logic on each individual radio field in the matrix (note the specific syntax for checking the value of a checkbox choice `[checkbox(choice_code)] = '1'` for `choice_code` is checked):

[image]

The ranking option in the matrix config means only one "Best" can be selected throughout the matrix. This means only those choices selected from the checkbox appear in the matrix, and among those, only one can be 'best', only one 'second best', and so on.

[image]

There is an external module called Survey UI Tweaks that adds the ability to structure this rank matrix as a drag-and-drop field, as below:

[image]

Unfortunately, while it will only record the options (best, second, etc) that you define in the field, it will allow respondents to rank all selected options:

[image]

But anything from 4 onwards is simply not recorded in the database, which is a bit of a drawback. Notice 'bananas' is not given a ranked value, as '4' could not resolve to anything.

[image]